# Is it ok to define a function using SFINAE that requires non-existance of the function?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, sfinae, template-instantiation

The code in this question is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73307583/4117728). I am a little confused about how this produces the output it does, and whether it is all well defined

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct bar {};
void foo(bar) {}
struct moo {};

template<class T>
struct is_fooable {
    static std::false_type test(...);
    
    template<class U>
    static auto test(const U& u) -> decltype(foo(u), std::true_type{});
    static constexpr bool value = decltype(test(std::declval<T>()))::value;
};
template<class T> inline constexpr bool is_fooable_v = is_fooable<T>::value;

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!is_fooable_v<T>,void> foo(T) {}

int main() {
    std::cout << is_fooable_v<bar>;
    std::cout << is_fooable_v<moo>;
    foo(bar{});
    foo(moo{});   
}
```

[Output with gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/scYEqdfjE) (same with clang and msvc):

```
10
```

If `is_fooable_v<moo>` is `false` then SFINAE does not discard the `foo` template and then `moo` is "fooable", though `is_fooable_v<moo>` is `false` nevertheless.

I find it confusing that the trait has only limited use, because it cannot tell if `moo` is "fooable" after it was used to define `foo<T>` with `T==moo`. Irrespective of that potential confusion, is the code well defined?

Is it ok to define a function based on a trait that tests if the function does exist?

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't UB, it's just that `is_fooable` does not know about `std::enable_if_t<!is_fooable_v<T>,void> foo(T)` since it is declared after so `moo` doesn't have a `foo` to be called with in it's eyes.

Comment: @NathanOliver its probably a poor question, I can't really put my finger on what could be wrong with the code. Though I was rather surprised to see this work. I found it highly suspicious, but if theres nothing wrong with it its actually rather cool :)

Comment: Of the top of my head, GCC had some issues with that. Encountered this while trying to writing a neibloid-like function object. It was supposed to do ADL-for customisation, and fallback on a "default" in case that one didn't exist. Not fun times.

Comment: Recusion in type traits didn't occur to me (when I wrote the answer being reflected upon) and I'm quick to throw a type trait into the mix so.... your question is brilliant.  I have a feeling that it alls falls out naturally as long as a trait is not depending on itself. Looking forward to answers to this question!

Comment: Isn't this IFNDR due to [\[temp.point\]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.point#7.sentence-4)? The static data member `value` has, for a given specialization of the `is_fooable` class template, two points of instantiation (immediately after the class template specialiation, at namespace scope, and "[...] the point after the declaration-seq of the translation-unit is also considered a point of instantiation"), and for the `is_fooable<moo>` specialization, these two have different meanings.

Comment: @dfrib not sure if that applies, because the paragraph starts with "A specialization for a class template has at most one point of instantiation within a translation unit." so the way I understand it the last sentence (about specializations with different meanings only applies to different translation units. Though I guess it was a Q&A about that very section I had remembered when I saw this code.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Note that the whole /7 paragraph starts with "A specialization [...] of a [...] **static data member of a class template** may have multiple points of instantiations **within a translation unit**, and in addition to the points of instantiation described above," and ends with "A specialization for any template may have points of instantiation in multiple translation units. If two different points of instantiation give a template specialization different meanings according to the one-definition rule, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.".

Comment: ... As I read it, the note on class templates that you quote simply mentions that class template themselves only have at most one point of instantiation, but that does not apply to other templated entities as e.g. static data members of class templates. But temp.point is tricky, so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 12):

##### tl;dr

- This pattern is well-defined
- `std::enable_if_t<!is_fooable_v<T>,void> foo(T)` is visible during the initialization of `is_fooable<T>::value`

  - but template argument substitution will fail for it, so `is_fooable<T>::value` will be `false`
- You can use a second trait class to detect both functions (e.g. `struct is_really_fooable` with the same definition as `is_fooable`)

---

##### 1. Disclaimer

This post only considers the C++20 standard.
I didn't check previous standards for conformance.

##### 2. Visibility of the templated `foo` function

The templated foo function (`template <typename T> std::enable_if_t<!is_fooable_v<T>,void> foo(T) {}`) is visible from within `is_fooable` and participates in overload resolution.

This is due to `test(std::declval<T>())` being dependent on `T` - so name lookup needs to consider both the context of the template definition **and** the context of the point of instantiation:

> [13.8.2 Dependent names [temp.dep] (2)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.res#temp.dep-2)
> If an operand of an operator is a type-dependent expression, the operator also denotes a dependent name.
> [ *Note:* Such names are unbound and are looked up at the point of the template instantiation ([[temp.point]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.res#temp.point)) in both the context of the template definition and the context of the point of instantiation ([[temp.dep.candidate]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.res#temp.dep.candidate)). — *end note* ]

```cpp
// [...]

template<class T>
struct is_fooable { // <-- Template definition
    static std::false_type test(...);
    
    template<class U>
    static auto test(const U& u) -> decltype(foo(u), std::true_type{});
    static constexpr bool value = decltype(test(std::declval<T>()))::value;
};

// is_fooable is dependent on T in this case,
// so the point of instantiation will be the point where is_fooable_v<T> is itself instantiated
template<class T> inline constexpr bool is_fooable_v = is_fooable<T>::value;

template <typename T>
// same as for is_fooable_v - 
std::enable_if_t<!is_fooable_v<T>,void> foo(T) {}

int main() {
    std::cout << is_fooable_v<bar>; // <-- Point of instantiation for is_fooable<bar>
    std::cout << is_fooable_v<moo>; // <-- Point of instantiation for is_fooable<moo>
    foo(bar{});
    foo(moo{});
}
```

So the templated `foo` function would not be visible from the template definition, but it would be visible from the point of instantiation - and since we need to look at both it will be considered for overload resolution within `is_fooable`.

Note: If the expression would not be dependent on the template parameter, e.g. `foo(12)`, then we would only need to consider the context of the template definition:

> [13.8 Name resolution [temp.res] (10)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.res#10)
> If a name does not depend on a [template-parameter](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.param#nt:template-parameter) (as defined in [[temp.dep]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.res#temp.dep)), a declaration (or set of declarations) for that name shall be in scope at the point where the name appears in the template definition; the name is bound to the declaration (or declarations) found at that point and this binding is not affected by declarations that are visible at the point of instantiation.

[13.8.5.1 Point of instantiation [temp.point] (7)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.point#7) does not apply in this case - we only have a single translation unit and only have a single instantiation point for each `is_fooable<T>` - so there will be no violation of the odr rule.

Note: You still need to be careful though if you use this in multiple translation units (but this basically applies to any trait-like template).
e.g. this would be a violation of the odr rule (ill-formed, ndr):

```cpp
// Translation unit 1
struct bar{};
void foo(bar) {}

template<class T> struct is_fooable { /* ... */ };

// would print 1
void test1() { std::cout << is_fooable<bar>::value << std::endl; }

// Translation unit 2
struct bar{};
// foo(bar) not defined before test2

template<class T> struct is_fooable { /* ... */ };

// would print 0
void test2() { std::cout << is_fooable<bar>::value << std::endl; }

// -> different definitions of is_fooable<bar>::value in different translation units
// -> ill-formed, ndr
```

---

##### 3. How `is_fooable<moo>::value` ends up being `false`

In essence this is an interesting application of constant expressions combined with SFINAE.

First we'll need to cover a few basic rules:

- Accessing a variable during its own initialization is undefined behaviour. (e.g. `int x = x;`)
  This is due to the following two rules: (emphasis mine)

  > [6.7.3 Lifetime [basic.life] (1)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.life#1)
  > [...] The lifetime of an object of type T begins when:
  >
  > - storage with the proper alignment and size for type T is obtained, and
  > - **its initialization (if any) is complete** [...]

  > [6.7.3 Lifetime [basic.life] (7)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.life#7)
  > [...] Before the lifetime of an object has started but after the storage which the object will occupy has been allocated [...], any glvalue that refers to the original object may be used but only in limited ways. [...] The program has undefined behavior if:
  >
  > - **the glvalue is used to access the object** [...]
- non-type template parameters must be **converted constant expressions**

  > [13.4.2 Template non-type arguments[temp.arg.nontype] (2)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.arg.nontype#2)
  > A [template-argument](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.names#nt:template-argument) for a non-type [template-parameter](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.param#nt:template-parameter) shall be a converted constant expression ([[expr.const]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const)) of the type of the [template-parameter](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.param#nt:template-parameter).

  - A converted constant expression must be a constant expression

    > [7.7 Constant expressions [expr.const] (10)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const#10)
    > A *converted constant expression* of type T is an expression, implicitly converted to type T, where the converted expression is a constant expression [...]
  - A constant expression is a core constant expression:

    > [7.7 Constant expressions [expr.const] (11)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const#11)
    > A *constant expression* is either a glvalue core constant expression that refers to an entity that is a permitted result of a constant expression (as defined below), or a prvalue core constant expression [...]
  - So to wrap it up a non-type template parameter must have a value that is a core constant expression (ignoring the conversion part)

So now we can piece it together:

- Let's start with `std::cout << is_fooable_v<moo>;`: This will instantiate `is_fooable_v<moo>`, which in turn will instantiate `is_fooable<moo>::value`.
- So the initialization of `is_fooable<moo>::value` begins.

  - The overload resolution for `test()` takes place with both `test` functions as candidates

    - `test(...)` is straightforward and would always be a viable function (with a low priority)
    - `test(const U& u)` would be viable and will be instanciated

      - this in turn will result in the overload resolution of `foo(u)`, which also has 2 potential candidate functions: `foo(bar)` and `foo(T)`

        - `foo(bar)` is not viable, because `moo` is not convertible to `bar`
        - `foo(T)` would be viable and will be instanciated

          - during argument substitution into `foo(T)` we'll encounter a problem: `foo(T)` accesses `is_fooable<moo>::value` - which is still uninitialized (we're currently trying to initialize it)
          - this would be undefined behaviour normally - but because we're in a constantly evaluated context (non-type template arguments like the one of `std::enable_if_t` need to be *converted constant expressions*) a special rule applies: (emphasis mine)

            > [7.7 Constant expressions [expr.const] (5)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const#5)
            > An expression E is a *core constant expression* unless the evaluation of E, following the rules of the abstract machine ([[intro.execution]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro.execution)), would evaluate one of the following:
            > [...]
            >
            > - **an operation that would have undefined behavior as specified in [[intro]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro) through [[cpp]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/cpp) of this document** [ *Note:* including, for example, signed integer overflow ([[expr.prop]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.prop)), certain pointer arithmetic ([[expr.add]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.add)), [division by zero](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.mul), or certain [shift operations](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.shift) — *end note* ] ;
            >   [...]

            - [6.7.3 Lifetime [basic.life]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.life#1) is between [4 Intro [intro]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/intro) and [15 Preprocessing directives [cpp]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/cpp) so this rule applies to accessing a variable outside of its lifetime.
            - Therefore the `is_fooable_v<T>` within `std::enable_if_t<!is_fooable_v<T>,void>` is **not a core constant expression**, which the standard mandates for non-type template parameters
            - So this instanciation of `foo(T)` would be ill-formed (and not undefined behaviour)
          - so template argument substitution for `foo(T)` fails and will not be a viable function
        - there are no viable functions that `foo(u)` could match
      - template argument substitution for `U` in `test(const U& u)` fails due to no viable function that could be called for `foo(u)`
    - `test(const U& u)` is no longer viable due to `foo(u)` being ill-formed - but `test(...)` is still viable
    - `test(...)` will be the best viable function (and the error from `test(const U& u)` will be swallowed due to SFINAE)
  - `test(...)` was picked during overload resolution, so `is_fooable<moo>::value` will be initialized to `false`
- The initialization of `is_fooable<moo>::value` is complete

So this is completely standard-conforming due to undefined behaviour not being allowed in constant expressions (and therefore `foo(T)` will always cause a substitution failure during the initialization of `is_fooable<T>::value`)

This is all contained within the `is_fooable` struct, so even if you first call `foo(moo{});` you would get the same result, e.g.:

```cpp
int main() {
  foo(moo{});
  std::cout << is_fooable_v<moo>; // will still be false
}
```

It's essentially the same sequence as above, just that you start with the function `foo(T)`, which then causes the instanciation of `is_fooable_v<T>`.

- (see above for the sequence of events that take place)
- `is_fooable_v<T>` gets initialized to `false`
- argument substitution of `foo(T)` succeeds
  -> `foo<moo>(moo{})` will be called

Note: If you comment out the `test(...)` function (so SFINAE won't be able to suppress the substitution failure from `test(const U& u)`) then your compiler should report this substitution error (it is ill-formed and therefore there should be a diagnostic message).
This is the result from gcc 12.1: (only the interesting parts)
[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3rz9d4s7j)

```
In instantiation of 'constexpr const bool is_fooable<moo>::value':
error: no matching function for call to 'is_fooable<moo>::test(moo)'
error: no matching function for call to 'foo(const moo&)'
note:  candidate: 'template<class T> std::enable_if_t<(! is_fooable_v<T>), void> foo(T)'
note:  template argument deduction/substitution failed:
error: the value of 'is_fooable_v<moo>' is not usable in a constant expression
note:  'is_fooable_v<moo>' used in its own initializer
note:  in template argument for type 'bool'
```

---

##### 4. Remarks

You can shorten your `is_fooable` trait if you use a C++20 requires clause, e.g.:

```cpp
template<class T>
constexpr bool is_fooable_v = requires(T const& t) { foo(t); };
```

Notice that you **can't** use a concept, because concepts are never instanciated.

If you want to be able to also detect `foo(T)` you could do so by just defining a second trait.
The second trait would not partake in the initialization shenanigans that `is_fooable` uses and therefore would be able to detect the `foo(T)` overload:
[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/nshzvP4fj)

```cpp
struct bar {};
void foo(bar) {}
struct moo {};

template<class T>
constexpr bool is_fooable_v = requires(T const& t) { foo(t); };

template<class T>
constexpr bool is_really_fooable_v = requires(T const& t) { foo(t); };

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!is_fooable_v<T>,void> foo(T) {}

int main() {
    foo(moo{});
    std::cout << is_fooable_v<moo>; // 0
    std::cout << is_really_fooable_v<moo>; // 1
}
```

And yes, if you want to you can layer those traits on top of each other, e.g.:
[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/5Yb599de9)

```cpp
struct a {};
struct b {};
struct c {};


void foo(a) { std::cout << "foo1" << std::endl; }

template<class T> inline constexpr bool is_fooable_v = requires(T const& t) { foo(t); };
template<class T> inline constexpr bool is_really_fooable_v = requires(T const& t) { foo(t); };
template<class T> inline constexpr bool is_really_really_fooable_v = requires(T const& t) { foo(t); };


template <class T, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, b>>>
std::enable_if_t<!is_fooable_v<T>,void> foo(T) { std::cout << "foo2" << std::endl; }

template <class T>
std::enable_if_t<!is_really_fooable_v<T>,void> foo(T) { std::cout << "foo3" << std::endl; }

int main() {
    foo(a{});
    foo(b{});
    foo(c{});
    std::cout << "a: "
              << is_fooable_v<a> << " "
              << is_really_fooable_v<a> << " " 
              << is_really_really_fooable_v<a> << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b: "
              << is_fooable_v<b> << " "
              << is_really_fooable_v<b> << " " 
              << is_really_really_fooable_v<b> << std::endl;
    std::cout << "c: "
              << is_fooable_v<c> << " "
              << is_really_fooable_v<c> << " " 
              << is_really_really_fooable_v<c> << std::endl;
    /* Output:
       foo1
       foo2
       foo3
       a: 1 1 1
       b: 0 1 1
       c: 1 0 1
    */
}
```

that will get really really confusing though, so i would not recommend it.

Comment: ...... madre mia ..... One of these days I'm going to learn how to read the specs. I may have to retire to have the time. I'm glad you came to the conclusion that my initial type trait was well formed though :-)

Comment: What's the difference between `b` & `c`? Why different behavior?

Comment: @Red.Wave The second `foo` has `std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T, b>>` as a defaulted template parameter type, that causes the difference between `b` and `c`.

Answer (score -2):

Before I give the answer let me do a recap on why the code works like that:

---

The "problem" lies in these two lines:

```cpp
template<class T> inline constexpr bool is_fooable_v = is_fooable<T>::value;

template <typename T> std::enable_if_t<!is_fooable_v<T>,void> foo(T) {}
```

Now imagine the `foo(moo)` is being created by the second line. It has to execute `std::enable_if<!is_fooable_v<T>, void>` which has in turn execute `!is_fooable_v<T>`. What is the value of such expression with `T = moo`? Of course to find that out we have to instantiate `is_fooable_v<moo>`. After some calculations the compiler instantiates this boolean to `false`.

And that's it: now the `is_fooable_v<moo>` *since that point* is now equal `false` **in every other evaluation of that expression** ([temp.inst#7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp#inst-7)). So when you use it in the `main()` function:

```cpp
std::cout << is_fooable_v<moo>;
```

it became "fixed" to that value.

To prove that look what if you add to those two lines this extra line:

```cpp
template<> inline constexpr bool is_fooable_v<moo> = true;
```

this of course makes the `foo(moo{});` line unable to compile, but it makes also both lines with `std::cout` printing ones.

[Look for yourself](https://godbolt.org/z/37b88c56j).

---

As for the question:

> Is it ok to define a function based on a trait that tests if the function does exist?

Well, the answer depends if you can actually find some use for this "trick".

If, for example, you are making a library then using this technique you can make a default implementation of a function based on if the user of your library actually provides his/her own. Of course there is a catch, I wanted to show in my recap above: you can't use the `is_fooable_v<>` template in your code to test for existence of such user-provided function.

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't see how this is an answer to the question, considering that it just repeats the analysis that was implied by the question and the comments below it, and, most of all, considering that there's a language-lawyer tag.

Comment: Also this question is tagged language-lawyer.

Comment: maybe you misunderstood the question. I admit it could be phrased better, though " Irrespective of that potential confusion, is the code well defined?" means: I am aware that the trait evaluates to `false` and that this causes the SFINAEd function to be defined. I am also aware that one might expect (including myself) once the function is defined, the trait does evaluate to `true`. However, I could be fine with this confusion, so lets put that aside. The question is: Is the code legal? And the `language-lawyer` tag implies: Can you point me to some sections in the standard that are relevant